# Usage of MultiDexApplication causes Robolectric test for the Application class to break

Tags: android, robolectric, dex

Adding Multi dex support with the support v4-r21 using gradle def (https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/JW9x4pcB1rj)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "info.osom.multidex"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
    it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
    if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
        dx.additionalParameters = []
    }
    dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
    dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=$projectDir/multidex.keep".toString()
}
```

Now this works for the app itself and I'm able to build and deploy but when I run a robolectric test for my Application class, I get a failure from ZipUtils (which is caught in MultiDex.java). The other tests are running fine. Here is the trace -

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Multi dex installation failed (/Users/Code/android-code/android/. (Is a directory)).
>       at android.support.multidex.MultiDex.install(MultiDex.java:178)
>       at android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication.attachBaseContext(MultiDexApplication.java:39)
>       at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:181)
>       at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
>       at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:155)
>       at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:430)
>       at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
>       at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
>       at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)

Comment: I think its looking for an apk but finds the root project folder instead

Comment: Nobody has any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Robolectric unit tests fail after Multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280756/robolectric-unit-tests-fail-after-multidex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known bug, wait for a fix: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1328

Answer (score 51):

Add **multi-dex shadow** as your **dependency**:

```
testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0"
```

This will mock MultiDex.install call and do nothing, since there are no dex in Robolectric

Comment: helped, thanks. just need to make sure the version in this line is identical to the one in:     testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'  (Otherwise it wont work)

Comment: This worked for me! as above said, make sure your versions match.

Answer (score 3):

You needs to create an Application class that inherits from MultiDexApplication
attachBaseContext (Context) is Override, and crush an exception if run on JavaVM.

```
  import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

    public class Application extends MultiDexApplication {

       @Override
       protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
          try {
            super.attachBaseContext(base);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            String vmName = System.getProperty("java.vm.name");
            if (!vmName.startsWith("Java")) {
               throw e;
            }
          }
       }
    }
```