# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.classname" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, android-multidex

Not always but sometimes i see this exception in logcat while running my app

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.classname" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

The app doesn't crash and this `com.example.classname` is present in my project.
I am using android studio 2.2 and I am using multidex for our project.
my doubt is this issue is because of multidex.

Any idea about how can i fix this exception?

our build.gradle file is big. 
i am adding some part of it

```
     compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 22
    multiDexEnabled true
    ......
    }
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        testCompile('org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0') {
            exclude group: 'org.robolectric', module: 'robolectric'
        }
}
```

And in custom Application class

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest part related to the application, your build.gradle file and your custom application if you have one?

Comment: Can you show the `build.gradle` file where you enabled `multiDexEnabled`?

Comment: why you have added both library in dependencies ?

Comment: shadows-multidex is for robolectric.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512170/usage-of-multidexapplication-causes-robolectric-test-for-the-application-class-t

Comment: add multidex in dependency party like as and robolectric also...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

Comment: its already inside dependencies {} here i didn't add but now i have updated.

Answer (score -1):

Trying using these few lines in your application class which would be

```
extend android.app.Application
```

and this will definately work :

Because of low memory , android created two dex files, so

```
   attachBaseContext()
```

mangage this issue

```
   @Override
     protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
       }
```

and in gradle of your application

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.YourApplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    multiDexEnabled true

    }

   dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

Comment: Multidex is enabled but using attachBaseContext() function will  solve this issue

Comment: But how do you know that hasn't already been done? I'm just saying, it seems like you're guessing and have provided the steps necessary to enable multidex even though the question said that was already done

Comment: I had seen this issue many time in many of my projects and of my colleagues , they had already enabled their multidexEnabled true in their gradle, but  by adding attachBaseContext() function  in Application class fixed their issue .As Android creates more than one dex files due to which classnotfound excption come

Comment: Sure, but that is a necessary step to enable Multidex anyway. Just adding that one line to Gradle only means that Gradle will *support* multidex building.

Comment: Besides, extending the Application class isn't completely necessary if `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` is in the manifest

Comment: we already have attachBaseContext() in our custom Application class